# How to make Adobe XD to Flutter code responsive without using any hardcoded values?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, adobe, flutter-plugin, adobe-xd

I was trying to convert one of my screens designed in Adobe XD to Flutter code but was not quite satisfied with it's outcome. The screen that I imported looks something like this:
[image: Adobe XD screen design]

From UI point of view, everything was nearly similar, but when I looked at the code, all the UI components had hard coded values in it.

***For example, start and end values, height and width values, all were hardcoded with numbers like 8 or 10 or so on.***

Also, the code didn't have pre-defined flutter widgets in it but consisted of PIN widgets just for the sake of drawing out the UI on the screen.

**NOTE:** I am aware of the responsive design option present in Adobe XD and even after turning that ON, the code was not responsive because of the hardcoded values.

**What should be done to make the import completely responsive without any hardcoded values in the code?**

**If not completely, then what's the nearest possible solution for it?**

I am sharing the code that was generated by Adobe XD to Flutter plugin for better understanding of my problem.

```
    return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(start: 18.0, end: 0.0),
        Pin(size: 70.7, start: 14.3),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 72.0, end: 0.0),
              Pin(start: 34.7, end: 0.0),
              child:
                  // Adobe XD layer: '↳ Cancel Links to' (shape)
                  Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(16.0, 71.8),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 11.0,
          height: 21.0,
          child:
              // Adobe XD layer: 'back' (group)
              Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                width: 11.0,
                height: 21.0,
                child:
                    // Adobe XD layer: 'back (1)' (group)
                    Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 11.0,
                      height: 21.0,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 11.0,
                            height: 21.0,
                            child: SvgPicture.string(
                              _svg_8im13w,
                              allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(start: 37.0, endFraction: 0.6693),
        Pin(size: 25.0, start: 70.0),
        child: Text(
          'Checkout',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontSize: 18,
            color: const Color(0xff000000),
            letterSpacing: 0.007379999935626983,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            height: 2.8333333333333335,
          ),
          textHeightBehavior:
              TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
      ),
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(start: 16.0, end: 16.0),
        Pin(startFraction: 0.218, endFraction: 0.6342),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
              Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                  color: const Color(0xfff4f6fb),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 22.0, start: 11.0),
              Pin(size: 22.0, middle: 0.2041),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
                    Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.elliptical(9999.0, 9999.0)),
                        color: const Color(0xfff4f6fb),
                        border: Border.all(
                            width: 1.0, color: const Color(0xff5093fe)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(start: 5.0, end: 5.0),
                    Pin(start: 5.0, end: 5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.elliptical(9999.0, 9999.0)),
                        color: const Color(0xff5093fe),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: const Color(0x29000000),
                            offset: Offset(0, 3),
                            blurRadius: 6,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(start: 50.0, endFraction: 0.5219),
              Pin(size: 23.0, middle: 0.1959),
              child: Text(
                'Work Location',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  letterSpacing: 0.006559999942779541,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  height: 2.8125,
                ),
                textHeightBehavior:
                    TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 81.0, start: 50.0),
              Pin(size: 20.0, middle: 0.53),
              child: Text(
                '0227485165',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontSize: 14,
                  color: const Color(0xff757575),
                  letterSpacing: 0.005739999949932098,
                  height: 1.5,
                ),
                textHeightBehavior:
                    TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(start: 50.0, end: 30.0),
              Pin(size: 20.0, middle: 0.81),
              child: Text(
                '325 Mansoura, Hay Aljamaa 122 Baker',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontSize: 14,
                  color: const Color(0xff757575),
                  letterSpacing: 0.005739999949932098,
                  height: 1.5,
                ),
                textHeightBehavior:
                    TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(start: 16.0, end: 16.0),
        Pin(startFraction: 0.383, endFraction: 0.4692),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
              Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                  color: const Color(0xfff4f6fb),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 22.0, start: 11.0),
              Pin(size: 22.0, middle: 0.2041),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
                    Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.elliptical(9999.0, 9999.0)),
                        border: Border.all(
                            width: 1.0, color: const Color(0xff000000)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 121.0, start: 50.0),
              Pin(size: 23.0, middle: 0.1959),
              child: Text(
                'Home Location',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  letterSpacing: 0.006559999942779541,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  height: 2.8125,
                ),
                textHeightBehavior:
                    TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 81.0, start: 50.0),
              Pin(size: 20.0, middle: 0.53),
              child: Text(
                '0227485165',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontSize: 14,
                  color: const Color(0xff757575),
                  letterSpacing: 0.005739999949932098,
                  height: 1.5,
                ),
                textHeightBehavior:
                    TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(start: 50.0, end: 30.0),
              Pin(size: 20.0, middle: 0.81),
              child: Text(
                '325 Mansoura, Hay Aljamaa 122 Baker',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontSize: 14,
                  color: const Color(0xff757575),
                  letterSpacing: 0.005739999949932098,
                  height: 1.5,
                ),
                textHeightBehavior:
                    TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(start: 16.0, endFraction: 0.6907),
        Pin(size: 23.0, start: 130.0),
        child: Text(
          'Shipping To:',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontSize: 16,
            color: const Color(0xff000000),
            letterSpacing: 0.006559999942779541,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            height: 2.8125,
          ),
          textHeightBehavior:
              TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
      ),
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(size: 98.0, start: 16.0),
        Pin(size: 23.0, middle: 0.5932),
        child: Text(
          'Select Card:',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontSize: 16,
            color: const Color(0xff000000),
            letterSpacing: 0.006559999942779541,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            height: 2.8125,
          ),
          textHeightBehavior:
              TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
      ),
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(end: 16.0, startFraction: 0.7093),
        Pin(size: 20.0, start: 132.0),
        child: Text(
          'Add Location',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontSize: 14,
            color: const Color(0xff000000),
            letterSpacing: 0.005739999949932098,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
            height: 3.2142857142857144,
          ),
          textHeightBehavior:
              TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        ),
      ),
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(start: 16.0, end: 16.0),
        Pin(size: 58.0, end: 14.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0xff5093fe),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(startFraction: 0.328, endFraction: 0.3253),
        Pin(size: 25.0, end: 30.0),
        child: Text(
          'Confirm Order',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontSize: 18,
            color: const Color(0xffffffff),
            letterSpacing: 0.007379999935626983,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            height: 2.5,
          ),
          textHeightBehavior:
              TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(size: 37.0, start: 16.0),
        Pin(size: 22.2, middle: 0.6571),
        child:
            // Adobe XD layer: 'mastercard' (group)
            Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 22.2, end: 0.0),
              Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
              child: SvgPicture.string(
                _svg_pw5872,
                allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 22.2, end: 0.0),
              Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
              child: SvgPicture.string(
                _svg_n5xemp,
                allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 11.1, end: 0.0),
              Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
              child: SvgPicture.string(
                _svg_dfb4m8,
                allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 22.1, start: 0.0),
              Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
              child: SvgPicture.string(
                _svg_z81ipn,
                allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 22.1, start: 0.0),
              Pin(start: 0.1, end: 0.0),
              child: SvgPicture.string(
                _svg_ebq0b3,
                allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(size: 11.2, middle: 0.425),
              Pin(start: 0.1, end: 0.0),
              child: SvgPicture.string(
                _svg_rlw6ie,
                allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(start: 1.1, end: 1.1),
              Pin(size: 5.9, middle: 0.5036),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 2.3, middle: 0.3773),
                    Pin(start: 0.5, end: 0.0),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_202jdk,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 3.8, middle: 0.4631),
                    Pin(size: 4.7, end: 0.0),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_jkc2c7,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 4.1, middle: 0.6705),
                    Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_tcaz9m,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 3.8, middle: 0.1701),
                    Pin(start: 1.1, end: 0.1),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_8jim3n,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 3.3, middle: 0.2812),
                    Pin(start: 1.0, end: 0.1),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_pq3haq,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 4.6, end: 0.0),
                    Pin(start: 0.1, end: 0.0),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_mkbn4f,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 5.8, start: 0.0),
                    Pin(start: 0.1, end: 0.1),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_xnr112,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 2.9, middle: 0.5643),
                    Pin(size: 4.6, end: 0.1),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_4w1zj7,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 3.8, middle: 0.7846),
                    Pin(start: 1.1, end: 0.1),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_9wfjdb,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 2.9, end: 4.1),
                    Pin(size: 4.6, end: 0.1),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_lbzk8e,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Pinned.fromPins(
              Pin(start: 1.1, end: 1.1),
              Pin(size: 5.9, middle: 0.5036),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 2.5, middle: 0.375),
                    Pin(start: 0.5, end: 0.0),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_dra0bs,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 3.2, middle: 0.4731),
                    Pin(size: 4.7, end: 0.0),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_4y5d4m,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Pinned.fromPins(
                    Pin(size: 3.5, middle: 0.6766),
                    Pin(start: 0.0, end: 0.0),
                    child: SvgPicture.string(
                      _svg_es75w6,
                      allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(startFraction: 0.1733, endFraction: 0.5707),
        Pin(size: 23.0, middle: 0.6578),
        child: Text(
          'MasterCard',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontSize: 16,
            color: const Color(0xff000000),
            letterSpacing: 0.006559999942779541,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            height: 2.8125,
          ),
          textHeightBehavior:
              TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
      ),
      Pinned.fromPins(
        Pin(startFraction: 0.1733, endFraction: 0.4587),
        Pin(size: 23.0, middle: 0.7757),
        child: Text(
          'Cash On Delivery',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontSize: 16,
            color: const Color(0xff000000),
            letterSpacing: 0.006559999942779541,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            height: 2.8125,
          ),
          textHeightBehavior:
              TextHeightBehavior(applyHeightToFirstAscent: false),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```